# Using notebooks with splitters in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm experimenting with wxWidgets (I'm new to it), and I'm trying to make a window with a notebook and tabs on it, and then inside the notebook, I want a splitter so that I can show a tree on the left, and another notebook on the right, which will have more tabs.  But it's causing problems.  So far, I've extended a wxFrame and here's what's inside of it:

```
wxPanel* parent = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);

wxBoxSizer* vbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

wxNotebook* notebook = new wxNotebook(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, this->GetSize());
wxPanel* notebookWindow = new wxPanel(notebook, wxID_ANY);

parent->SetSizer(vbox);
Center();
Maximize(true);

notebook->SetSize(this->GetSize());
notebook->AddPage(notebookWindow, wxT("Tab one"), true, 0);
notebook->AddPage(notebookWindow, wxT("Tab two"), true, 0);

wxSplitterWindow* splitterWindow = new wxSplitterWindow(notebookWindow, wxID_ANY);

wxTreeCtrl* tree = new wxTreeCtrl(splitterWindow, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(0, 0), wxSize(200, 1000), wxTR_HAS_BUTTONS | wxTR_LINES_AT_ROOT | wxTR_HIDE_ROOT | wxTR_EDIT_LABELS);

wxTreeItemId rootID = tree->AddRoot(wxT("Root"));
wxTreeItemId item1ID = tree->AppendItem(rootID, wxT("Item 1"));
wxTreeItemId item2ID = tree->AppendItem(rootID, wxT("Item 2"));
wxTreeItemId item3ID = tree->AppendItem(rootID, wxT("Item 3"));
wxTreeItemId item4ID = tree->AppendItem(item2ID, wxT("Item 4"));

vbox->Add(splitterWindow, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 5);
```

When I run this, I get an error which occurs at the final line that says:

"CheckExpectedParentIs(w, m_containingWindow)" failed in wxSizer::DoInsert(): Windows managed by the sizer associated with the given window must have this window as parent, otherwise they will not be repositioned correctly.

But then it appears correctly.  But I'd still like to get rid of the error.  I think it's saying that if I add the splitterWindow to the vbox then the vbox should be set as a sizer to the parent of the splitterWindow, which is notebookWindow, so that I'd change the line "parent->SetSizer(vbox);" to "notebookWindow->SetSizer(vbox);", but when I try that, even though the error disappears, so does the tree!

Also:

- I had messed around with the splitter to try to get it to display stuff properly, including the extra notebook with tabs on the right side of it, within the main notebook, but I had no luck with that either.
- I also need to be able to use the mouse to drag and move the splitter position, but that doesn't seem to be happening either.
- I need the tree and the nested notebook to move and resize accordingly when the splitter moves.
- And I also noticed that when I click the tabs, it changes which one is selected, but other than that, nothing happens.  I need to be able to show different trees on different tabs of the main notebook, so that when I click different tabs the view will change, and the nested notebook must be able to show different content on different tabs as well (otherwise what's the point of using tabs at all?).

I've searched for tutorials for this stuff, and all I've found is stuff like https://zetcode.com/gui/wxwidgets, which doesn't seem to really address these issues.  Can someone please help me?

**UPDATE:**

I put this here because it's too long to add as a comment, so I'm not sure where else to put it.

I can't seem to get the graphical tools to install and work, so I'm just writing code directly.

I've made a separate window for each tab but I still get the error, and the stuff doesn't appear anymore.

Unfortunately, I'm so busy that I hardly ever have any time to work on code, and I make barely any progress each time, if any at all, so when I have a problem, weeks end up going by and it still doesn't work, even though it probably should have been fixed in less than an hour!

I appreciate your help, and I understand the teaching a man to fish philosophy, but it just doesn't work for me.  Can anyone *please* just fix my code so that I can see what was wrong with it, and so that it will *finally* work?

Here's what I have so far:

```
parent = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);

wxBoxSizer* vbox1 = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
wxBoxSizer* vbox2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

wxNotebook* notebook = new wxNotebook(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, this->GetSize());

wxPanel* firstWindow = new wxPanel(notebook, wxID_ANY);
wxPanel* secondWindow = new wxPanel(notebook, wxID_ANY);

firstWindow->SetSizer(vbox1);
secondWindow->SetSizer(vbox2);

Center();
Maximize(true);

notebook->SetSize(this->GetSize());
notebook->AddPage(firstWindow, wxT("Tab one"), true, 0);
notebook->AddPage(secondWindow, wxT("Tab two"), true, 0);

wxSplitterWindow* splitterWindow = new wxSplitterWindow(firstWindow, wxID_ANY);

wxTreeCtrl* tree = new wxTreeCtrl(splitterWindow, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(0, 0), wxSize(200, 1000), wxTR_HAS_BUTTONS | wxTR_LINES_AT_ROOT | wxTR_HIDE_ROOT | wxTR_EDIT_LABELS);

wxTreeItemId rootID = tree->AddRoot(wxT("Root"));
wxTreeItemId item1ID = tree->AppendItem(rootID, wxT("Item 1"));
wxTreeItemId item2ID = tree->AppendItem(rootID, wxT("Item 2"));
wxTreeItemId item3ID = tree->AppendItem(rootID, wxT("Item 3"));
wxTreeItemId item4ID = tree->AppendItem(item2ID, wxT("Item 4"));

vbox1->Add(firstWindow, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 5);
vbox2->Add(secondWindow, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 5);
```

Comment: when you start with wxWidgets and sizers it is hard to code everything by hand. Get some RAD tool - wxGlade, wxFormBuilder, wxCrafter, etc and design you GUI there. Then look at the code produced and try to understand what is different. (I recommend wxGlade - it is maintained and can generate the code based on the current wxWidgets version - I'm not a maintainre, just a happy user).

Comment: I'm trying to use wxGlade, but the instructions for installation are a bit vague, because it says "Unpack the archive to a known location and maybe add it to the path." but it doesn't specify what path it's talking about or how to add it.  It also says "On Windows, the win32 extensions should be installed" but I don't know about that either.  And it says "use whatever is required to start a python application on your platform", but I'm not sure if I have any interpreter or whatever I'd need for that.  I use C++.  I'll try this but I don't know if I make it to work.  Can you fix my code though?

Comment: I've checked all three of your suggestions and they have ridiculously complicated or otherwise vague installation instructions, or they require some entirely different IDE (I'm using Visual Studio .NET), but isn't there one that I can just download an installer file, run it to install a program, and then run that to generate my code?

Answer (score 0):

The code above is indeed wrong in multiple ways:

1. You're adding the same window (`notebookWindow`) twice to the notebook, which is not allowed. You need to create a new window for every page/tab.
2. You need to set the sizer containing the splitter with `notebookWindow`, i.e. the splitter parent, just as the assert message is telling you.

The code doesn't correspond to what you say you want to do as there is just a single notebook while you're speaking of two of them, but what you describe can certainly be done in the way you're doing it, just using the correct parents/sizers. The rule is simple: the window sizer may, and must, be used to manage children of this window only, not any other one.

Also, notwithstanding the advice in the comments, it's perfectly fine to not use a dialog editor when working with wxWidgets, but using XRC (whether handled by the editor or manually written) can indeed be simpler for more complex layouts and, especially, to avoid recompiling the code just to test a layout change (XRC can be loaded from external file).

Comment: Oh, so I make a window for each tab, and then the tab will automatically switch between them?  Well that would solve one problem easily enough - thanks!  Though technically, it seems to allow it the way I did it, but just gives a bad result.  As for prat 2, do you mean something like "notebookWindow->SetSizer(vbox);", replacing "parent" with "notebookWindow"?  Remember that when I tried that, the error goes away, but the tree also disappears!  SO that's no good.  I know I said I need two notebooks, but I figured I'd get one to work first and then add the other one.  I'll look into XRC.

Comment: Yes, you need a window for each tab. And I suspect your other problem will go away once you stop resisting the same window for two different tabs.

Comment: Hmm, we'll see, but hopefully I'll have time to work on it tomorrow morning, and then I'll know for sure.

Comment: I finally got time to work on it a bit more, but I still can't get it to work right!  See my edit in my original post (beginning where it says "UPDATE:").